# Соединить таблицы, полученные из вложенных селектов

Tags: sql, firebird

У меня есть следующий запрос:

```
select * from (
    select max(id), code
    from (
        select id, code from doc where code IN (
        '12-02-2021_1',
        '12-02-2021_2',
        '12-02-2021_3',
        '12-02-2021_4'
        )
    )
    group by 2
)
```

Мне нужно к этому запросу присоединить таблицу `config`, которая на основе поля `doc.state` присоединяет наименование состояния (`config.stname`), но простой следующий left join в firebird не работает в данном случае:

```
select * from ( select ... from ... group by ... ) seldocs
left join config conf on seldocs.id = conf.docid;
```

Может здесь есть какой-то особенный синтаксис для таких left join'ов? **Желательно без `with`**. *(версия firebird - 2.5).*

*ошибка: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid command. no column name specified for column number 1 in derived table SELDOCS.*

*ошибка 2 (после добавления "max(id) as id"): Column does not belong to referenced table.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -206.
Column unknown.
SELDOCS.STATE.
At line 13, column 31.*

Дополнение: если написать `select max(id) as id, code, state (select from select id, code, state (...)) group by 2,3`, то выдаст 8 документов (вместо четырёх), т.к. code не уникальный, а уникальный только id, и нужно выбрать именно `max(id)` из всех `doc` с одинаковым `code`.

Comment: *не работает в данном случае* - нужно подкреплять такие слова текстом ошибки или приводить вывод селекта и объяснять, почему это не то, что нужно, иначе непонятно, что эта фраза означает вообще

Comment: А подзапрос-то тут зачем? причём даже в начальном запросе...

Comment: @CrazyElf, ошибка: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid command. no column name specified for column number 1 in derived table SELDOCS.

Comment: @Akina, doc.code не уникальный в моём случае, id уникальный

Comment: `... select max(id) AS id, code ...`

Comment: Ну да, ошибка говорит о том, что колонку надо как-то назвать. Если бы там просто колонки были, оно бы само справилось, а поскольку там преобразование стоит оно не знает, как такую колонку назвать автоматом

Comment: @Akina, Теперь такая ошибка на строке "from (", и я хз как group by тут правильно написать, ибо после сортировки group by по state результат может содержать state из старого документа (с таким же code) или выбрать все документы с таким "code", хотя нужны только max(code): Column does not belong to referenced table.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -206.
Column unknown.
STATE.
At line 3, column 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select * 
from (select max(id) AS id, code
      from doc 
      where code IN ( '12-02-2021_1',
                      '12-02-2021_2',
                      '12-02-2021_3',
                      '12-02-2021_4' )
      group by code ) AS subquery
left join config on subquery.id = config.docid;
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, там была небольшая ошибка, config присоединяется у меня так: left join config conf on seldocs.state = conf.id; (в conf.id содержится state документа)

Comment: @IvanSilkin Вы опять критические для вопроса факты размещаете хрен знает где, да к тому же без подробностей... *в conf.id содержится state документа* - я должен догадаться, как из значения `id` извлекается значение `state`, да? так вот - я не догадался.

Comment: В принципе всё правильно, у вас так, как и должно быть, но у нас в базе нету поля docid в таблице config :_) в этом-то, я думаю, и суть, что эта связь таблиц нужна, и в качестве новой таблицы, я так думаю, чтобы хранить разные состояния и изменение состояний документов (у нас её нет – в config просто словарь по разным состояниям )...

Comment: @IvanSilkin Напишите наконец нормально вопрос. Выложите CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, пример данных (3-5 записей на таблицу, в виде INSERT INTO), требуемый результат для этих данных и подробные пояснения к нему. Нам отсюда не видно, что там где есть и чего нет.

Comment: Я это лучше в другой вопрос позже вложу. Здесь у меня проблема была скорее просто с лефт джоинами таблиц и синтаксисом при выборке из двух вложенных селектов.